# Google GCM server returns 404 error

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to sent message from my server to phone, by PHP.
Here is my code:

```
    $apiKey = "AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    $registrationIDs = array( $c2dmId );

    $url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

    $headers = array( 
                        'Authorization: key='.$apiKey,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );

    $fields = array(
                    'collapse_key'      => $collapseKey,
                    'data'              => array( 
                        "type"      => $msgType,
                        "extra"     => $msgExtra,
                        "uuid"      => $uuid,
                        "user_id"   => $userId),
                    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                    );

    print (json_encode($fields));
    echo "<br/>";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $resultInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

    echo "resultinfo: $resultInfo <br>";
    foreach ($resultInfo as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key => $value <br>";
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    die ("Result: $result");
```

Where $c2dmId is just registrationId which I send to server from phone. As a result I get (in $result variable):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Not Found</H1>
<H2>Error 404</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And I don't know why. Can anyone help? Documentation dosen't say anything about 404 code, so I really don't know what is going on.

Comment: 404 says that the service url that you try to connect does not exists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: hmm... I know it, but I really don't know why it says this in my case. I get url from [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html), so it should be good, dosen't it? I really don't know why I get 404 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, I completely forgot about this question, sorry for that. I already find out what was the problem.
Earlier I used that code which I posted before to send messages via C2DM. I made only a few improvements to adjust it to GCM. And one of variables ($msgExtra) could equal null in some case. It was intended behaviour and with C2DM it worked just fine.
Unfortunately, when you try to pass null in JSON via GCM you get 404 error, although GCM documentation says nothing about that...
So code which I posted is good as far as you don't try to send null.
Solution of my problem is to replace null value with something like "".
And once again - sorry that I post it just now, I completely forgot about this question.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I am sure this will help alot of people.

Comment: Confirm that this helped me. This is significant flaw in GCM as far as I am concerned; it doesn't really support JSON if it flips like this when you send a valid serialized value for your app to consume. The information that some field is null (and not 0 or '' or another null impersonator) may be exactly what you need to push to your app.

Comment: After hours of debugging I found my answer here. Damn it GCM, you should write proper JSON parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a Browser API Key from the Google APIs Console, and use it instead of the server key in the "Authorization" header. Once you do that, this error will go away.

This is caused by a serious mistake in the GCM Documentation that states you should use a Server Key in the Authorization header (as written [Over here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately it dosen't help. I've read about this mistake on StackOverflow, so I used "Key for browser apps (with referers)", which was automatically generated when I turned on GCM. After your post, I generated new key, but it also dosen't work. Still 404. But thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

may be its already resolved for you.But here is the working version of your code which i tested on device.

```
<?php

$apiKey = "AI.....";

$registrationIDs = array( "You registration key"  );

$url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key='.$apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

$msgType = "hello";
$msgExtra = "rock";
$uuid = '1234';
$userId = '5678';

/* data you need to define message you want to send in APP.For ex: here myssg in what i am fetching at client side, so in notification it will show hello. You can change accordingly. */ 
$fields = array(
                'collapse_key'      => $collapseKey,
                'data'              => array( 
                    "mymsg"      => $msgType,
                    "extra"     => $msgExtra,
                    "uuid"      => $uuid,
                    "user_id"   => $userId),
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                );

print (json_encode($fields));
echo "<br/>";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$resultInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo "resultinfo: $resultInfo <br>";
foreach ($resultInfo as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value <br>";
}

curl_close($ch);
die ("Result: $result");
?>
```

This will not give you 404 error.Hope this will help you or some looking for server side implementation in PHP .