# GCM RETURNS 404 ERROR

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send natification message to my device but ı have this error

```
 com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 404
```

and I'm not really sure why.

Here is my code

```
package com.avilyne.gcm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

public class GCMBroadcast extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String myApiKey = "AIzaSyAHUdHy-7o-XJS59mhAzUUoTqn-EUb9s88";
    private static final String regID = "APA91bHUcUuv3ViHfIkZg7YyKeiq3Ta1WVqEWrdIs9AZwdQ2nfSA2r-9BcH4WxRnAb0mHXEqEi7WMngPKQyrzcP5EhCFLqsprJpscHLIyi8gK80SdMpHluLBk3iRUCQTShY8szNvy3f4IBiGZv75ioe-Ai8wnZLqKw";
    private List<String> androidTargets = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GCMBroadcast() {

        super();

        androidTargets.add(regID);

    }


    /*protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

            doPost( req, resp);*/


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userMessage = "";
        userMessage = req.getParameter("Message");

        Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
        Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("Message", userMessage)
                .build();

        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, androidTargets, 1);

        if (result.getResults() != null) {
            int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
            if (canonicalRegId != 0) {

            }
        } else {
            int error = result.getFailure();
            System.out.println("Broadcast failure: " + error);
        }

        req.setAttribute("Message", userMessage);

        req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

}
```

When ı try this code without doGet method its return "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL" this error. İf ı add doGet method and called doPost method in doGet. it returns "HTTP Status 500 - HTTP Status Code: 404(  Not Found

## Not Found

### Error 404

)"

The full error message I get when I try to send the message to the server is:

```
 com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 404(<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Not Found</H1>
<H2>Error 404</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:367)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:261)
    at com.avilyne.gcm.GCMBroadcast.doPost(GCMBroadcast.java:49)
    at com.avilyne.gcm.GCMBroadcast.doGet(GCMBroadcast.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help? The documentation dosen't say anything about a 404 code.

That is web.xml code;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GCMBroadcast</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.avilyne.gcm.GCMBroadcast</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GCMBroadcast</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GCMBroadcast</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

and that is index.jsp code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<%
    // retrieve our passed CollapseKey and Message parameters, if they exist.

    String message  = "Generic Broadcast Message";

    Object msgObj =  request.getAttribute("Message");

    if (msgObj != null) {
        message = msgObj.toString();
    }

%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Android GCM Broadcast</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>GCM Broadcast Demo</h2>

    <form action="GCMBroadcast" method="post">
        <label>Broadcast Message </label>

        <br/><textarea name="Message" rows="3" cols="60" ><%=message %> </textarea> 
        <br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Post your code for the class Sender. But most likely you have the wrong URL to the GCM server. It should be a HTTPS POST request to:

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when I tried to send a message via GCM (I did it from PHP, but I don't think that really matters here).

Here is a link to my question:

[Google GCM server returns 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451143/google-gcm-server-returns-404-error/11702291#11702291)

I already found out what my problem was(and answered my own question :) ).
Error appeared every time I tried to pass null value to GCM. I replaced null by empty string and all is good. I don't know why, documentation doesn't say anything about this problem, but that is it.

So this may be why you are getting this error or maybe you just have bad link to the GCM server.

Answer (score 0):

The com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender class that Google provides has the URL embedded in it.  The best option might be to step through the doPost() via an Eclipse debug session to see if the error actually occurs at the sender.send() moment, or at the result.getResults() moment or somewhere beforehand.

It might be that an error is occurring prior to those points (are the "Message" and "CollapseKey" values properly passed?), and is only being trapped later in the process, giving you the stack trace you see.